# Concatenate @ to angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to open outlook when someone clicks on the emails. I am using angularjs to generate the email address. There is some issue where email id is generated with @ concatenation. How can I concatenate @ to an angular expression?

```
 <a href="mailto:{{Item.AssignedTo}}@sitename.com?Subject=Re:{{Item.Title}} " target="_top">
    Email someone
    </a>
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: syntax issue, it is not considering @ after expression

Comment: I haven't seen any issue check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/9na5k3np/

Comment: just hint: you should use `ng-href`/`ng-attr-href` directives for templating meaningful attributes to not confuse..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it as single expression also change `href` to `ng-href`

```
<a ng-href="{{'mailto:'+Item.AssignedTo+'@sitename.com?Subject=Re:'+Item.Title}} " target="_top">
```

checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/9na5k3np/)

Answer (score 2):

You should make a function and pass your `values` as parameters.

```
 <a href="myFunction(Item.AssignedTo,Item.Title)" target="_top">
 Email someone
</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.myFunction= function(assignedTo,title) {
  return "mailto"+assignedTo+"@sitename.com?Subject=Re:"+title;
}
```

Also, you have to change `href` property to `ng-href`.

Comment: You should put the `myFunction` between `{{ }}`